# php array scope issue - returns last row from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am changing mysqli connections to prepared statements, I always come across this issue, when I am putting values in an array, I'm wondering if someone could explain why I do this incorrectly every time. When I print the returned array from the function it only shows me the last stored values in the array, as opposed to every row in the array.

```
function getResults($db) {
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT inv_id, serial_num, equip_id, equip_title, equip_cat, input_date, date_modified FROM equip_inv");

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $num_of_rows = $statement->num_rows;
    $statement->bind_result($invId, $serial, $equipId, $equipTitle, $equipCat, $inputDate, $dateMod);

    while ($statement->fetch()) {
        $resultArray = array();
        $resultArray['inv_id'] = $invId;
        $resultArray['serial_num'] = $serial;
        $resultArray['equip_id'] =  $equipId;
        $resultArray['equip_title'] = $equipTitle;
        $resultArray['equip_cat'] = $equipCat;
        $resultArray['input_date'] = $inputDate;
        $resultArray['date_modified'] = $dateMod;
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reseting `$resultArray` in each loop. You can create a new array `$results = array();` and push `$resultArray` to it in each loop. Try :

```
function getResults($db){


$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT inv_id, serial_num, equip_id, equip_title, equip_cat, input_date, date_modified FROM equip_inv");

$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $statement->num_rows;
$statement->bind_result($invId, $serial, $equipId, $equipTitle, $equipCat, $inputDate, $dateMod);
$results = array();

while ($statement->fetch()){
    $resultArray = array();
    $resultArray['inv_id'] = $invId;
    $resultArray['serial_num'] = $serial;
    $resultArray['equip_id'] =  $equipId;
    $resultArray['equip_title'] = $equipTitle;
    $resultArray['equip_cat'] = $equipCat;
    $resultArray['input_date'] = $inputDate;
    $resultArray['date_modified'] = $dateMod;
    $results[] = $resultArray;
    }
    return $results;
}
```